# Wordpress Multisite - When a user signs-up on main site, how to add the user to a subsite

Tags: multisite, users

I am setting up a Wordpress multisite network, where users may subscribe to one or more services on the main site and may have access to content on subsite. The access on subsite will depend on the service they subscribe on the main site.

What I want to do using some code is when a user registers on main site, I can add that user to the subsite and add some attribute/meta-data to define what access the user has on the subsite (may be I will use memberpress to manage the access)

My main question is what code can be used to add a user to subsite when he signs up main site?

Comment: Do not have time to develop custom code to achieve this but if you are comfortable to use plugin then this plugin will help you to achieve this. https://wordpress.org/plugins/join-my-multisite/

Comment: Thanks @VinodDalvi though I need the help in code preferably as I would need to do more things attached to this i.e. the user will be signed up through a Woocommerce purchase on main site and then user will have selective access by enabling a specific membership type based on what they purchase on main site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run [`add_user_to_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_to_blog) after user creation.

You can hook on [`user_register()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) to get newly created user ID and pass it and any conditional assignments to your callback that runs `add_user_to_blog()`.

Comment: Does this mean @skotperez's answer is more correct, or does this work also? He references `wpmu_activate_user`... just curious.

Answer (score 2):

I complete [@hwl](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/118366/hwl)'s answer:

Most of the times, in a Multisite instance of WordPress, user registration includes an activation step.

In this case, it is necessary to hook actions on `wpmu_activate_user`; actions hook on `user_register` will be ignored. For instance:

```
my_function($user_id)   {
    // to add a user to main site (id=1) as a subscriber add_user_to_blog can be used
    // more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_to_blog
    add_user_to_blog( '1', $user_id, 'subscriber' );
}
add_action('wpmu_activate_user','my_function',10,1);
```

Comment: Hi @skotperez... I was wondering, could you possibly give an example of how the question could be solved entirely? Ie to take a multiuser registration event and cause it to create a new user on the main site (ie, "// do stuff"...)?

Comment: To add a user to any site of the multisite you can use the [add_user_to_blog](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_to_blog) function. So you can include this function instead of the "do stuff" comment. I edit my answer to include this code.